# WebDriverException: Message: unable to set cookie while switching cookies from Session to Selenium's Chrome on Instagram

Tags: python, selenium, cookies, instagram, selenium-chromedriver

I'm trying to make a login request to Instagram through an HTTP request (Thanks to Python's "requests" module) and then port the result to Selenium's chromedriver, in order to have the user already logged in.
I'm using the "[requestium](https://github.com/tryolabs/requestium)" module to try that.
As I successfully manage to login inside the website through Session, it seems that it blocks me in switching to the driver in order to have the already logged in page.
This is the error that the console prints me

```
DevTools listening on ws://127.0.0.1:12779/devtools/browser/73b726a1-520f-4d08-8982-a9ada65ead2b
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "requestiumTest.py", line 124, in <module>
    s.transfer_session_cookies_to_driver()  # You can maintain the session if needed
  File "C:\Users\gforcell\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\requestium\requestium.py", line 114, in transfer_session_cookies_to_driver
    'expiry': c.expires, 'domain': c.domain})
  File "C:\Users\gforcell\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\requestium\requestium.py", line 235, in ensure_add_cookie
    self.add_cookie(cookie)
  File "C:\Users\gforcell\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 872, in add_cookie
    self.execute(Command.ADD_COOKIE, {'cookie': cookie_dict})
  File "C:\Users\gforcell\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 312, in execute
    self.error_handler.check_response(response)
  File "C:\Users\gforcell\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\errorhandler.py", line 242, in check_response
    raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: unable to set cookie
  (Session info: chrome=66.0.3359.139)
  (Driver info: chromedriver=2.36.540470 (e522d04694c7ebea4ba8821272dbef4f9b818c91),platform=Windows NT 10.0.15063 x86_64)
```

While this is the code for reproducing it

```
from requestium import Session, Keys
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.common.exceptions import TimeoutException
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
import os
from seleniumrequests import Chrome
from os.path import join
import platform
import json
import hashlib
import hmac
import six.moves.urllib as urllib


def findPathForDriver():
    lookfor = "chromedriver.exe" if platform.system() == "Windows" else "chromedriver"
    placeWhereToStart = "C:\\" if platform.system() == "Windows" else "/"
    for root, dirs, files in os.walk(placeWhereToStart):
        if lookfor in files:
            with open('path.txt', 'w') as f:
                f.write(join(root, lookfor))
            return join(root, lookfor)

def generate_signature(data, IG_SIG_KEY, SIG_KEY_VERSION):
    body = hmac.new(IG_SIG_KEY.encode('utf-8'), data.encode('utf-8'),hashlib.sha256).hexdigest() + '.' + urllib.parse.quote(data)
    signature = 'ig_sig_key_version={sig_key}&signed_body={body}'
    return signature.format(sig_key=SIG_KEY_VERSION, body=body)

def generate_device_id(seed):
    volatile_seed = "12345"
    m = hashlib.md5()
    m.update(seed.encode('utf-8') + volatile_seed.encode('utf-8'))
    return 'android-' + m.hexdigest()[:16]

def generate_UUID(uuid_type):
    import uuid
    generated_uuid = str(uuid.uuid4())
    if uuid_type:
        return generated_uuid
    else:
        return generated_uuid.replace('-', '')

def get_seed(*args):
    m = hashlib.md5()
    m.update(b''.join([arg.encode('utf-8') for arg in args]))
    return m.hexdigest()

def send_request(endpoint, post=None, login=False, with_signature=True):
    global last_response
    global last_json
    global s
    s.headers.update({
        'Connection': 'close',
        'Accept': '*/*',
        'Content-type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8',
        'Cookie2': '$Version=1',
        'Accept-Language': 'en-US',
        'User-Agent': USER_AGENT
        })
    try:
        if post is not None:  # POST
            if with_signature:
                post = generate_signature(post, IG_SIG_KEY, SIG_KEY_VERSION)
            response = s.post('https://i.instagram.com/api/v1/' + endpoint, data=post)
        else:  # GET
            response = s.get('https://i.instagram.com/api/v1/' + endpoint)
    except Exception as e:
        print("Eccezione per colpa dell'endpoint " + endpoint)
        return False
    if response.status_code == 200:
        last_response = response
        last_json = json.loads(response.text)
        return True
    else:
        return False

DEVICE_SETTINTS = {
    'manufacturer': 'samsung',
    'model': 'herolte',
    'device': 'SM-G960F',
    'android_version': 26,
    'android_release': '8.0'
}
#41.0.0.13.92
USER_AGENT = 'Instagram 10.26.0 Android ({android_version}/{android_release}; 640dpi; 1440x2560; {manufacturer}; {device}; {model}; samsungexynos8890; en_US)'.format(
    **DEVICE_SETTINTS)
IG_SIG_KEY = '4f8732eb9ba7d1c8e8897a75d6474d4eb3f5279137431b2aafb71fafe2abe178'
EXPERIMENTS = 'ig_android_disk_cache_match_journal_size_to_cache_max_count,ig_android_ad_move_carousel_indicator_to_ufi_universe,ig_android_universe_video_production,ig_android_live_follow_from_comments_universe,ig_android_ad_watchandinstall_universe,ig_android_live_analytics,ig_android_video_captions_universe,ig_android_offline_location_feed,ig_android_ontact_invite_universe,ig_android_insta_video_reconnect_viewers,ig_android_live_broadcast_blacklist,ig_android_checkbox_instead_of_button_as_follow_affordance_universe,ig_android_ufi_redesign_video_social_context,ig_android_stories_surface_universe,ig_android_verified_comments_universe,ig_android_preload_media_ahead_in_current_reel,android_instagram_prefetch_suggestions_universe,ig_android_direct_inbox_tray_suggested_user_universe,ig_android_direct_blue_tab,ig_android_light_status_bar_universe,ig_android_asset_button_new_content_animation,ig_android_async_network_tweak_universe,ig_android_react_native_lazy_modules_killswitch,ig_android_instavideo_remove_nux_comments,ig_video_copyright_whitelist,ig_android_ad_sponsor_label_story_top_design_universe,ig_android_business_action,ig_android_direct_link_style,ig_android_live_heart_enhancements_universe,ig_android_preload_item_count_in_reel_viewer_buffer,ig_android_auto_retry_post_mode,ig_android_fix_render_thread_crash,ig_android_shopping,ig_fbns_preload_default,ig_android_gesture_dismiss_reel_viewer,ig_android_ad_logger_funnel_logging_universe,ig_android_direct_links,ig_android_links_receivers,ig_android_ad_impression_backtest,ig_android_offline_freshness_toast_10_12,ig_android_invites_without_token_universe,ig_android_immersive_viewer,ig_android_mqtt_skywalker,ig_fbns_push,ig_android_react_native_universe,ig_android_special_brush,ig_android_live_consumption_abr,ig_android_story_viewer_social_context,ig_android_explore_verified_badges_stories_universe,ig_android_video_loopcount_int,ig_android_enable_main_feed_reel_tray_preloading,ig_android_ad_watchbrowse_universe,ig_android_react_native_ota,ig_android_discover_people_icon_in_others_profile,ig_android_log_mediacodec_info,ig_android_enable_back_navigation_nux_universe,ig_android_cold_start_feed_request,ig_video_use_sve_universe,ig_android_offline_explore_10_14,ig_android_stories_teach_gallery_location,ig_android_http_stack_experiment_2017,ig_android_stories_device_tilt,ig_android_pending_request_search_bar,ig_android_fb_topsearch_sgp_fork_request,ig_android_animation_perf_reporter_timeout,ig_android_new_block_flow,ig_android_direct_address_links,ig_android_share_profile_photo_to_feed_universe,ig_android_stories_private_likes,ig_android_text_background,ig_android_stories_video_prefetch_kb,ig_android_su_activity_feed,ig_android_live_stop_broadcast_on_404,ig_android_render_iframe_interval,ig_android_boomerang_entry,ig_android_camera_shortcut_universe,ig_android_fetch_fresh_viewer_list,ig_android_ad_media_url_logging_universe,ig_android_phone_confirm_rate_limit_language_universe,ig_android_keep_http_cache_on_user_switch,ig_android_facebook_twitter_profile_photos,ig_android_full_user_detail_endpoint,ig_android_direct_sqlite_universe,ig_android_family_bridge_share,ig_android_search,ig_android_insta_video_consumption_titles,ig_android_live_notification_control,ig_android_camera_universe,ig_android_instavideo_audio_only_mode,ig_android_live_video_reactions_consumption_universe,ig_android_swipe_fragment_container,ig_creation_growth_holdout,ig_android_live_save_to_camera_roll_universe,ig_android_ad_cta_redesign_universe,ig_android_sticker_region_tracking,ig_android_unified_inbox,ig_android_offline_main_feed_10_11,ig_android_chaining_teaser_animation,ig_android_business_conversion_value_prop_v2,ig_android_redirect_to_low_latency_universe,ig_android_feed_header_profile_ring_universe,ig_family_bridges_holdout_universe,ig_android_following_follower_social_context,ig_android_video_keep_screen_on,ig_android_profile_photo_as_media,ig_android_insta_video_consumption_infra,ig_android_sms_consent_in_edit_profile,ig_android_infinite_scrolling_launch,ig_in_feed_commenting,ig_android_live_broadcast_enable_year_class_2011,ig_android_direct_phone_number_links,ig_android_direct_share_sheet_ring,ig_android_stories_weblink_creation,ig_android_histogram_reporter,ig_android_network_cancellation,ig_android_react_native_insights,ig_android_insta_video_audio_encoder,ig_android_family_bridge_bookmarks,ig_android_dash_for_vod_universe,ig_android_direct_mutually_exclusive_experiment_universe,ig_android_stories_selfie_sticker,ig_android_ad_add_per_event_counter_to_logging_event,ig_android_rtl,ig_android_direct_send_auto_retry,ig_android_direct_video_autoplay_scroll,ig_android_promote_from_profile_button,ig_android_share_spinner,ig_android_profile_share_username,ig_android_sidecar_edit_screen_universe,ig_promotions_unit_in_insights_landing_page,ig_android_save_longpress_tooltip,ig_android_constrain_image_size_universe,ig_android_business_new_graphql_endpoint_universe,ig_ranking_following,ig_android_universe_reel_video_production,ig_android_sfplt,ig_android_offline_hashtag_feed,ig_android_live_skin_smooth,ig_android_stories_posting_offline_ui,ig_android_direct_add_local_thread_in_inbox,ig_android_swipe_navigation_x_angle_universe,ig_android_offline_mode_holdout,ig_android_non_square_first,ig_android_insta_video_drawing,ig_android_react_native_usertag,ig_android_swipeablefilters_universe,ig_android_analytics_logger_running_background_universe,ig_android_save_all,ig_android_reel_viewer_data_buffer_size,ig_android_disk_cache_has_sanity_check,ig_direct_quality_holdout_universe,ig_android_family_bridge_discover,ig_android_react_native_restart_after_error_universe,ig_story_tray_peek_content_universe,ig_android_profile,ig_android_high_res_upload_2,ig_android_http_service_same_thread,ig_android_remove_followers_universe,ig_android_skip_video_render,ig_android_live_viewer_comment_prompt_universe,ig_android_search_client_matching,ig_explore_netego,ig_android_boomerang_feed_attribution,ig_android_explore_story_sfslt_universe,ig_android_rendering_controls,ig_android_os_version_blocking,ig_android_encoder_width_safe_multiple_16,ig_android_direct_video_autoplay,ig_android_snippets_profile_nux,ig_android_e2e_optimization_universe,ig_android_disk_usage,ig_android_save_collections,ig_android_live_see_fewer_videos_like_this_universe,ig_android_live_view_profile_from_comments_universe,ig_formats_and_feedbacks_holdout_universe,ig_fbns_blocked,ig_android_instavideo_periodic_notif,ig_android_empty_feed_redesign,ig_android_marauder_update_frequency,ig_android_suggest_password_reset_on_oneclick_login,ig_android_live_special_codec_size_list,ig_android_enable_share_to_messenger,ig_android_live_video_reactions_creation_universe,ig_android_live_hide_viewer_nux,ig_android_channels_home,ig_android_sidecar_gallery_universe,ig_android_live_using_webrtc,ig_android_insta_video_broadcaster_infra_perf,ig_android_business_conversion_social_context,android_ig_fbns_kill_switch,ig_android_retry_story_seen_state,ig_android_react_native_universe_kill_switch,ig_android_stories_book_universe,ig_android_all_videoplayback_persisting_sound,ig_android_cache_layer_bytes_threshold,ig_android_comment_deep_linking_v1,ig_android_business_promotion,ig_android_anrwatchdog,ig_android_qp_kill_switch,ig_android_ad_always_send_ad_attribution_id_universe,ig_android_2fac,ig_direct_bypass_group_size_limit_universe,ig_android_promote_simplified_flow,ig_android_share_to_whatsapp,ig_fbns_dump_ids,ig_android_ad_show_mai_cta_loading_state_universe,ig_android_skywalker_live_event_start_end,ig_android_toplive_verified_badges_universe,ig_android_live_join_comment_ui_change,ig_android_draw_button_new_tool_animation,ig_video_max_duration_qe_preuniverse,ig_android_http_stack_kz_debug,ig_request_cache_layer,ig_android_carousel_feed_indicators_universe,ig_android_new_optic,ig_android_mark_reel_seen_on_Swipe_forward,ig_fbns_shared,ig_android_capture_slowmo_mode,ig_android_save_multi_select,ig_android_mead,ig_android_video_single_surface,ig_android_offline_reel_feed,ig_android_video_download_logging,ig_android_last_edits,ig_android_exoplayer_4142,ig_android_snippets_haptic_feedback,ig_android_gl_drawing_marks_after_undo_backing,ig_android_mark_seen_state_on_viewed_impression,ig_android_live_backgrounded_reminder_universe,ig_android_disable_comment_public_test,ig_android_user_detail_endpoint,ig_android_comment_tweaks_universe,ig_android_add_to_last_post,ig_save_insights,ig_android_live_enhanced_end_screen_universe,ig_android_ad_add_counter_to_logging_event,ig_android_sidecar,ig_android_direct_split_new_message_button,ig_android_grid_video_icon,ig_android_ad_watchandlead_universe,ig_android_progressive_jpeg,ig_android_offline_story_stickers,ig_android_direct_inbox_unseen_hint,ig_android_top_live_titles_universe,ig_android_video_prefetch_for_connectivity_type,ig_android_ad_holdout_16m5_universe,ig_android_sync_on_background_enhanced,ig_android_upload_reliability_use_fbupload_lib,ig_android_samsung_app_badging,ig_android_offline_commenting,ig_android_insta_video_abr_resize,ig_android_insta_video_sound_always_on,ig_android_disable_comment'
SIG_KEY_VERSION = '4'

path = findPathForDriver()
s = Session(webdriver_path=path,
            browser='chrome',
            default_timeout=15)

username = <insert_username>
password = <insert_password>
device_id = generate_device_id(get_seed(username, password))
uuid = generate_UUID(True)
last_response = None
last_json = None

if (send_request('si/fetch_headers/?challenge_type=signup&guid=' + generate_UUID(False), login=True)):
    data = json.dumps({
        'phone_id': generate_UUID(True),
        '_csrftoken': last_response.cookies['csrftoken'],
        'username': username,
        'guid': uuid,
        'device_id': device_id,
        'password': password,
        'login_attempt_count': '0',
        })
    if send_request('accounts/login/', data, True):
        print("Tutto ok")
        is_logged_in = True
        user_id = last_json["logged_in_user"]["pk"]
        rank_token = "{}_{}".format(user_id, uuid)
        print(rank_token)
        ranktoken = rank_token
        token = last_response.cookies["csrftoken"]

s.transfer_session_cookies_to_driver()  # You can maintain the session if needed
s.driver.get('http://www.instagram.com')
```

From what I could gather, it looks as Chrome doesn't like the cookies that were previously generated, though they don't look like corrupted at all.
The error that the browser is showing is "too many requests"

Answer (score 7):

I was running into the same error using requests and selenium. You need to get  a page on the domain first before you can set the cookies

```
driver.get(login_url)
for cookie in s.cookies:
    driver.add_cookie({
        'name': cookie.name, 
        'value': cookie.value,
        'domain': cookie.domain
    })

driver.get(dashboard_url)
```

Answer (score 0):

This error message...

```
selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: unable to set cookie
```

...implies that **WebDriverException** was raised while trying to set cookie.

The **cookie** error seems to be coming out of the **version compatibility** between the binaries you are using as follows :

- You are using *chromedriver=2.36*
- Release Notes of [*chromedriver=2.36*](https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/2.36/notes.txt) clearly mentions the following :

> Supports **Chrome v63-65**

- You are using *chrome=66.0*
- Release Notes of [*ChromeDriver v2.38*](https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/2.38/notes.txt) clearly mentions the following :

> Supports **Chrome v65-67**

So there is a clear mismatch between the *ChromeDriver* version (**v2.36**) and the *Chrome Browser* version (**v66.0**)

### Solution

- Upgrade *ChromeDriver* to  current [**ChromeDriver v2.38**](https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/chromedriver/downloads) level.
- Keep *Chrome* version at ***Chrome v66.x*** levels. ([as per ChromeDriver v2.38 release notes](https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/2.38/notes.txt))
- *Clean* your *Project Workspace* through your *IDE* and *Rebuild* your project with required dependencies only.
- Use [*CCleaner*](https://www.ccleaner.com/ccleaner) tool to wipe off all the OS chores before and after the execution of your *test Suite*.
- If your base *Web Client* version is too old, then uninstall it through [*Revo Uninstaller*](https://www.revouninstaller.com/revo_uninstaller_free_download.html) and install a recent GA and released version of *Web Client*.
- Take a *System Reboot*.
- Execute your `@Test`.

Comment: Thank you for the answer! I've updated the driver but I still get the same issue

Answer (score 0):

Apparently there's no solution to this, even after DebanjanB's answer.
I found a workaround which perfectly works for me though: logging in through Selenium and then switch the cookies to the Session object of [requestium](https://github.com/tryolabs/requestium) and viceversa works perfectly.